# How can I identify puns in the Hebrew Bible?

Tags: hebrew, figure-of-speech, pun

The [Bible](http://manyfacesofbiblicalhumor.com/bible_puns) sometimes uses words with multiple meanings to the effect of an intentional [pun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun) or wordplay.  Punning seems especially common in [Hebrew](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1891/68).  I think that being aware of these literary devices offers an important insight into the tone and nature of the Biblical text.

But for people who aren't Hebrew speakers (or even those who are), how can I identify puns?  And when a pun is identified, how can determine if the suggested double-meaning is plausible or implausible?

Comment: Got mine. It would be a great resource. However, asking for guidance on plausibility may be a bit much. Plausibility is determined by context of a potential double-entendre. Agreement is difficult to obtain because of the very nature of the hidden meaning... it is hidden. You 'get' a joke or you don't. You may draw a picture to help someone get it, but you don't debate the plausibility that it is a joke.

Comment: Puns are the hardest thing to translate.  Any type of humor risks being lost in translation, but puns are almost guaranteed.

Comment: As of now, none of the answers give any real example of pun or double meaning. Seeing from other questions about double meaning, I doubt that people are even aware about what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translators often point out these sorts of puns in [footnotes](http://classic.net.bible.org/bible.php?book=Gen&chapter=40#n29) and they are even more commonly mentioned in commentaries.  For instance, here's one I found many years ago when I read the [NIV Study Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIV_Study_Bible):

Genesis 40:12-13 ([NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2040&version=NIV))

> “This is what it means, ” Joseph said to him. “The three branches are three days.  Within three days Pharaoh will lift up your head and restore you to your position, and you will put Pharaoh’s cup in his hand, just as you used to do when you were his cupbearer.

Genesis 40:18-19 ([NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2040&version=NIV))

> “This is what it means,” Joseph said. “The three baskets are three days. Within three days Pharaoh will lift off your head and impale your body on a pole. And the birds will eat away your flesh.”

So the same phrase, "lift up your head" is used to signify a good result and a bad one.  The humor is dry and quite dark.

Comment: *NWT Ref* has a footnote on Isaiah 28:10 explaining it to be a pun of some sort.

Comment: Even more than a pun the cup bearer and the baker parallel the elements of communion, where bread is Christ's body (which died like the baker) and wine is the promise of life (since he'll drink it with us in resurrection). Puns are the warp and woof of sensus plenior.

Comment: @Bob: Interesting.  I hadn't thought of that connection before.

Comment: @Jon and Elohim has the puns Alo Khoom and l'chaim meaning 'not dark' or  'light' and 'life'.  I believe this is the source for John 1.

Comment: @Monica: Sounds like I should open the question so that you can answer.

Comment: In English, similarly sounding words with different meanings are classified generally as puns. There are more technical terms that could be used. Hebrew has so many different methods of doing word-play that we would be remiss not to take notice of them, even if we only refer to them by a generic name in English.  I would hope that the question refers to the generic usage so that we don't miss the richness of all the other methods.

Comment: Homophones aren't the only kinds of puns. Changing vowels, changing related consonants, and swapping consonants are all types of puns. These are all used in Hebrew by the sages and more types as well. For plausibility of Elohim see: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/460/how-should-john-1-be-interpreted

Comment: As for constraining the meaning, in Midrash the sages can come up with some pretty wild and contradictory stuff. Sensus plenior is constrained by these rules: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/368/how-does-sensus-plenior-differ-from-allegory-gnosticism-kaballah-and-midras

Comment: The 22 letters of the Hebrew alphabet divide into 5 phonetic groups, based on their origin in the mouth's vocal system:

    the throat: א (alef) ח (chet) ה (hei) ע (ayin)
    the palate: ג (gimel) י (yud) כ (kaf) ק (kuf)
    the tongue: ז (zayin) ש (shin) ס (samech) ר (raish) צ (tzadik)
    the teeth: ד (dalet) ט (tet) ל (lamed) נ (noon) ת (tav)
    the lips: ב (bet) ו (vav) מ (mem) פ (pai)

Phonetically, any two letters of the same origin can be interchanged. Thus, there are many Hebrew words whose proximity in meaning stems from their phonetic equivalence.

Comment: the throat: א (alef) ח (chet) ה (hei) ע (ayin) Phonetically, any two letters of the same origin can be interchanged.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3709/discussion-between-bob-jones-and-monica-cellio)

Answer (score 3):

**Proper pun**

The English word 'pun' is equivalent to the Hebrew 'al tiqre . . . ellaʾ (“do not read . . . but”) which allows the interpreter to exchange one vowel or consonant for another.

In practice:
The 22 letters of the Hebrew alphabet divide into 5 phonetic groups, based on their origin in the mouth's vocal system: This list started with the phonetic assumption referred to by others and has been adjusted to a better list of what I have actually observed.

the throat: א (alef) ח (chet) ה (hei) ע (ayin) ו ('oo') י ('ee')

the palate: ג (gimel) כ (kaf)  ק (kuf) י (yud)  (Even the geneology of my mother's maiden name show's these varitations)

the tongue: ז (zayin) ש (shin) ס (samech) צ (tzadik)

the teeth: ד (dalet) ט (tet) ת (tav)

the lips: ב (bet) פ (pai)  *ו (vav)*

מ (mem) נ (noon)

Phonetically, in theory, any two letters of the same origin can be interchanged. Thus, there are many Hebrew words whose proximity in meaning derives from their phonetic equivalence. Words made in this way which do not have similar meanings can replace one another as 'puns'.

**Manufactured pun**

There is another kind of pun where words with different meanings differ only by  vowels added later. These puns were manufactured by the addition of vowels. In reality the original word contained the differing meanings. These are identified by dropping the late addition vowels. I use 'late addition vowels' because four of the original Hebrew letters actually act like vowels and are recognized as such by some sages.

**Embedded puns**

Then in Notarikon * every letter and every combination of letters is analyzed and understood in its own right.

The word bereisheet has three root letters (ROSh), a one letter prefix (B) and a two-letter suffix (eeT). But there are three two-letter sub root combinations as well. The two-letter sub-roots are a core idea which tie together three-letter roots formed by adding one of the four vowel letters. The roots are all aspects of the same core idea. Though they are not considered Hebrew puns technically, effectively the two-letter sub-roots can be considered embedded puns.

There are other word-play devices involving numerations and single-letter meanings, but these would be an even greater stretch to call them puns.

**Plausibility**

The plausibility of a pun depends on the interpretive structure. In literal methods most puns are viewed as accidental and incidental to the interpretation since only a single literal meaning is being sought. In Jewish Notarikon they all have meaning, and though we may not currently understand them, we are to wrestle until we find answers. In sensus plenior, the rules filter out the implausible, since only solutions which point to Christ are sought.

**For non-Hebrew speakers:**

As you are using your Hebrew dictionary, browse before and after the word you are looking at to see other words that share the same consonants. This will identify 'manufactured puns'.  Use the letter substitutions above and look up the new words formed to see if the word is productive within your interpretive framework.  These are the proper puns. You must be able to identify letters do do this as well as to identify two-letter embedded puns.

If you can pronounce the word, then any other word or combination of words that sounds like it is a candidate for being a pun. Ultimately it is child's play.

**Two-letter Subroots and Individual Letters**

> The word bereisheet has three root letters () and three additional
> letters: a oneletter prefix () and a two-letter suffix (). The
> three root letters spell the word rosh, meaning "head" or "beginning."
> However, in Notarikon **every letter and every combination of letters
> is analyzed and understood in its own right**. The first two letter
> unit that begins the whole Torah and the whole creative process is
> therefore BR. The second two letters are ShA , which means fire and the
> two suffix letters (YTh) are also considered as a third unit on their
> own.

[Harav Yitzchak Ginsburgh p.9](http://www.inner.org/torah_and_science/communications/E66-0219.pdf)

**Plausible puns**

Jesus was named Yeshua to fulfill the promise he would be called Emmanuel.  This makes no sense literally; they are different names.

Yeshua is a pun to Ya-shuach meaning 'God humbled'  This is Emmanuel - God with us.

God is love.  This doctrine is a Hebrew pun.  Father (God) come אב-בא is a pun of love אהבה.  Or by simply cutting short the last ה; Father 'ab' sounds like love: 'ahb'.

Comment: I am about 1/3 finished with a Hebrew dictionary of manufactured puns for non Hebrew readers. It will be free and online.

Comment: Hi Bob, do you know someone called 'hudson roper'? He posted [a question directed at you](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/enquiry-into-the-progress-of-your-dictionary) about the progress of your dictionary (I assume because he doesn't have the rep to comment here): "how is this going Bob? hopefully well. hudson"

Comment: In my view, you are combining processes *inside the text* with processes *outside the text*.

Comment: @hudson .. I got sidelined preaching the cross from the SP. . i am mentoring pastors and teaching children Hebrew using the SP. So it moves slowly as I build formations in the course of the studies. Much of it could be built up mechanically by a good programmer.

Comment: The only way Yeshua fulfills the prophecy of Immanuel is by pun. Ya shuach - God humbled, speaking of his incarnation. The use of punning by NT authors encourages us to do the same as a tool to understand prophetic riddle.

Comment: @JonEricson I added a couple samples of puns  for you.

Comment: @user947 without details I can only surmise at your view.One may be tempted to think that punning and word-play are imposed upon the text. However, the more familiarity  there is with notarikon, and the formation of words, the more it becomes apparent that it is the very warp and woof of the text, not merely a novelty.

Comment: As for the dictionary mentioned above, I could not draw a hard line between puns and formations/notarikon, so the work has grown significantly. Contact me if you have interests.

Comment: This is beautiful! But I would say that when neither Yeshua (Joshua) or Emmanuel should be interpreted as names. Rather, they are titles meaning "Savior" or "God within us".

Comment: @BobJones Interesting! FYI, the link you posted is broken.

Comment: Thanks @Robert. I hesitated putting it in since there is so much there that is anti-Christian. It was referenced to show the method of building words. The apostles used Notarikon, and that tool was also used, and twisted by the Kabalist.  I have notes elsewhere showing that Rabbi Blech intentionally distorts the method.

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/224637196/E66-0219-pdf ןis a paid copy of the broken link.

Comment: @Robert Many have suggested that "Savior" or "God's salvation" is close enough to Emmanuel that we need look no farther than the assertion they are the same.   Personally I am not content with 'close enough'. If this was the only evidence, ok take it or leave it. But "Yeshuah' is also "Yahwah" with a Sh ש in the middle or God with the increase by the Spirit (the bride) in his heart.  It is another riddle which brings us closer to "God with us". What's closer than the marriage.

Comment: @Robert  So we have two riddles using punning... Later Matthew says that Jesus was called a Nazarite to fulfill prophecy, but scholars have a hard time finding the prophecy. The use of puns allows us to find it.  But it's OT here. Perhaps Matthew was setting us up with the tools needed to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The technical term for puns/play-on-words is paronomasia.

For me, the best way to begin picking up on word intrigue was to find lists of various types and study them. However, as non-scholar in Hebrew, none of the references below would have helped without the Interlinear Scripture Analyzer (ISA) program found on scripture4all.**org**. Examples of this program can be found in another BH post [**here**](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/how-can-i-search-for-the-co-occurrence-of-two-words-ideally-searching-by-strong/47877#47877).

Below are some references that address paronomasia:

1. **[Figures of Speech Used in the Bible](https://archive.org/details/cu31924029277047)** by E.W. Bullinger ("The author sets out 217 distinct figures of speech present in Scripture....")  Available as free PDF (searchable) from archive.org or for purchase on Amazon as book or Kindle download, etc. Paronomasia examples begin on PDF p.363 (book p.307).
2. **[The Companion Bible Enlarged Type Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0825420997)** by E. W. Bullinger - Has In-page Notes that refer to *Figures of Speech* listed in Appendix 6. Available as PDF on archive.org. ["PDF WITH TEXT" is searchable.] When purchasing the book, I followed the helpful suggestion to get the enlarged print to make the in-page notes more readable.
3. [**Paronomasia in the Old Testament**](https://archive.org/details/paronomasiainold00casarich/page/n5/mode/2up) - Casanowicz 1894 pp.104. Available on archive.org - "B/W PDF" is searchable.  List of 502 cases of paronomasia in the OT begins on PDF p.52 (book p.44).

Comment: I know well about metaphors and figure. But I hesitate to open the third link for the pdf since I'm afraid it must be another collection of figure of speech. None of these and the other answers refers to pun or double meaning which is intended for rhetoric or jokes in modern language. You should have mentioned the quotes from the pdf if it really gives double meaning examples.

Answer (score 0):

What is a Hebrew pun? * When 2 words share the same root but have different meanings.

Example : Desert (Midbar, מִּדְבָּ֕ר) & Speak (Daber, דַּבְּר֞).

- In [Isaiah 40:2-3], the pun is Speak in the Desert.