# What tool or resource can I use to find a list of all the words that commonly co-occur with a word? (STRONG's)

Tags: greek, hebrew, tools-of-biblical-studies, resource-request

In the past I have asked [for tools to help me find references for the co-occurrence of multiple words](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/how-can-i-search-for-the-co-occurrence-of-two-words-ideally-searching-by-strong). Now I am asking for tools or resources that will allow me to enter one word and find a ranked list of others words that co-occur with that term. Ideally this search could be navigated by using STRONGS numbers, and would be available for OT and NT.

Comment: Co-occur suggests a word that occurs before OR after a word. That what you mean?

Comment: Yes, thank-you for asking

Comment: That's something for which I never had a need to search. Interested in reading answers though.

Comment: Are you familiar with search that look for multiple words in the same verse, and searches that do quotes?  You could do a search: "a b" OR "b a"

Comment: Yes, I linked to a question that led me to resources that show multiple words in the same verse in the question description; and I have found quoting resources elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you could do this with Accordance or Logos, though I don't know the exact search parameters myself. Do you have one of them?

Comment: Sorry I don't have either and I'm a bit naive in regard to both systems, so if you could explain either that would be appreciated. One example term is H3820.

Comment: I don't know of any existing handy resource. However, it is easy to build one quickly using AI N-gram technology.

Comment: Hi Tony, that sounds like a great suggestion, but I don't know how to make that happen. Are you able to expand on your thinking, for guidance?

Comment: See [How can I search for the co-occurrence of two words (ideally searching by Strong’s numbers)?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/how-can-i-search-for-the-co-occurrence-of-two-words-ideally-searching-by-strong)

Comment: Hi, that is one of my questions as I referenced above. It's a bit different but thanks for looking though :)

Comment: One way to think about it would be a reverse but complimentary function. Rather than looking for all the locations multiple words co-occur I am looking for all the words that co-occur with one term, regardless of location. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is provided for every word you look upon in Logeion:

https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%B6%CF%89%CE%AE

The only ways I can think of that this wonderful tool could be improved is if:

- it included BDAG
- the abbreviations in LSJ weren't so cryptic
- it could read my mind!

Answer (score 1):

TI.exe is freely available for academic usage. The program generates a word-occurrence matrix, a word co-occurrence matrix, and a normalized co-occurrence matrix from a set of lines (e.g., titles) and a word list.

http://leydesdorff.socsci.uva.nl/software/ti/index.htm